# Can you record video to external drive?

Tags: external-sd, storage, video-recording

If I connect an external ssd drive to the phone, it can browse its file system and write to it. Is there an app (or a setting) that allows me to record video directly to this external drive? The use case is shooting longer videos without stopping to transfer files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The "Open Camera" free software app from the F-Droid store lets you select the directory to save files.

I have just tried it with connecting a usb3 ssd with otg, and saved a video onto it.

https://f-droid.org/en/packages/net.sourceforge.opencamera/